# Parse.Object.fetchAll throwing unexpected Error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Been trying to debug this for over a day. Any help is very much appreciated.

In cloud code, I am attempting to invoke `Parse.Object.fetchAll()` on an array of `Parse.Role` pointers like so:

```
function loadRoles (company) {
    var roles = company.get('roles');
    console.log(roles.length); // 1
    console.log(roles[0].isNew()); // false
    promise = Parse.Object.fetchAll(roles)
     .fail(function(error){
       // This gets triggered with error 
       // {code: 101, message: 'All objects must exist on the server'}
     });
}
```

Given that the `roles` array contains a single `Parse.Role` that is both not `isNew()`, and has an `id`, I have no idea why I'm getting this error. I've tinkered with this for more than a day and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Dont really know Parse but from backbone it seem that you have an "idAttribute" for your role so is not new but don't exist from server ???

Comment: The server shows that the `Parse.Role` does exist.

Answer (score 1):

These roles have to exist on the server. Missing roles will cause that error if any of those objects have been removed in another operation.

**EDIT**: Use `Parse.Object.fetchAllIfNeeded(roles)` to avoid the error.

Comment: Looks less confusing now, well done. Please understand however, that I cannot upvote, for lack of knowhow on my side. So I can only tell that it is an answer - not whether it is a good one. Good luck.